# Angularjs create row for every 3 columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json nested array as shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vwsej/634/) and i want to display the elements as rows and columns. Each row should have 3 columns. I got this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vm3j4akp/98/) where same is done but it has simple json array.Here ng-if condition is used to break the data into rows.

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">{{products[$index]}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">{{products[$index + 1]}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">{{products[$index + 2]}}</div>
</div>
```

But in my case i want to display the array as shown in table structure shown in the fiddle. Also if there is any null objects then it should be ignored. How it can be done? Any idea?

Comment: Shouldn't that be solved with CSS?

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe I tried using same logic as mentioned in that fiddle but how do i get the data to be displayed from the nested array?

Comment: Nice Problem. Similar to this. But this problem should have better and easy solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037772/show-only-open-div-with-angular-if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simple try like this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uumrdL7z/)**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="products in items"> 
       <div ng-repeat="product in products">
          <div class="col-xs-4" >{{product.IDTYPE}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No . U didnt get my problem. I want to display the IDTYPE only. I have shown the pattern in the fiddle. see this http://jsfiddle.net/Vwsej/634/

Comment: @Navaneeth Is this you want

Comment: Yes, but can you tell me how rows are created?I don't see any conditional expression for creating rows

Comment: @Navaneeth it is working because  it is using bootstrap css `col-xs-4` for div, if you want to check remove `col-xs-4` from div and try

Comment: @Navaneeth Don't forget to mark it as answer if it satisfies your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl"> 
   <div> I want to display in below table structure</div><br/>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div class="row" ng-if="{$index%3==0}">
            <div ng-repeat="x in item" class="col-xs-4">{{x.IDTYPE}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
    "b": {
        "PRIMKEY": 96598.0,
        "IDTYPE": "userlogin",
        "USERID": "yes"
    },
    "c": {
        "PRIMKEY": 106974.0,
        "IDTYPE": "user_access",
        "USERID": "no"
    },
    "d": {
        "PRIMKEY": 107009.0,
        "IDTYPE": "Tel_ty",
        "USERID": "no"
    },
    "e": {
        "PRIMKEY": 60130.0,
        "IDTYPE": "new_user",
        "USERID": "no"
    },
    "f": {
        "PRIMKEY": 90885.0,
        "IDTYPE": "gen_id",
        "USERID": "001_0_2361"
    },
    "g": null,
    "h": {
        "PRIMKEY": 106996.0,
        "IDTYPE": "uyy_id",
        "USERID": "753"
    },
    "i": {
        "PRIMKEY": 106993.0,
        "IDTYPE": "qwe_id",
        "USERID": "585"
    },
    "j": {
        "PRIMKEY": 104831.0,
        "IDTYPE": "phone_login",
        "USERID": "122324"
    },
    "k": {
        "PRIMKEY": 85476.0,
        "IDTYPE": "windows_id",
        "USERID": "qwertr"
    }
}];
}
```

You can check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vwsej/641/)**.

Comment: No . U didnt get my problem. I want to display the IDTYPE only. I have shown the pattern in the fiddle. see this http://jsfiddle.net/Vwsej/634/

Comment: Updated my answer check it now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good solution if you use angular.filter
https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

Use **chunkBy**

Code will be look like

```
<div ng-repeat="productRow in products| chunkBy: 3">
   <div class="row" ng-repeat="product in productRow">
      <div class="col-xs-4">{{product}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is will fit your needs, let me know if it doesn't.

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    var items = [{
      "b": {
        "PRIMKEY": 96598.0,
        "IDTYPE": "userlogin",
        "USERID": "yes"
      },
      "c": {
        "PRIMKEY": 106974.0,
        "IDTYPE": "user_access",
        "USERID": "no"
      },
      "d": {
        "PRIMKEY": 107009.0,
        "IDTYPE": "Tel_ty",
        "USERID": "no"
      },
      "e": {
        "PRIMKEY": 60130.0,
        "IDTYPE": "new_user",
        "USERID": "no"
      },
      "f": {
        "PRIMKEY": 90885.0,
        "IDTYPE": "gen_id",
        "USERID": "001_0_2361"
      },
      "g": null,
      "h": {
        "PRIMKEY": 106996.0,
        "IDTYPE": "uyy_id",
        "USERID": "753"
      },
      "i": {
        "PRIMKEY": 106993.0,
        "IDTYPE": "qwe_id",
        "USERID": "585"
      },
      "j": {
        "PRIMKEY": 104831.0,
        "IDTYPE": "phone_login",
        "USERID": "122324"
      },
      "k": {
        "PRIMKEY": 85476.0,
        "IDTYPE": "windows_id",
        "USERID": "qwertr"
      }
    }];
    $scope.items = [];
    function format() {
      for (var item in items[0]) {
        var i = items[0][item]
        if (i) $scope.items.push(i.IDTYPE);
      }
    }
    format();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl" class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">{{items[$index]}}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">{{items[$index + 1]}}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">{{items[$index + 2]}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```